# VF page of managed package is not opening, says page does not exists

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package

I have create a managed package and added a VF page in the managed package and uploaded the package in appexchange(not yet published though). Now when i try to test the package by downloading it another developer org, i was able to install the package successfully as managed. Now when i try to open the VF page in the managed package i get the error that VF page doesn't exists.

Error message is 'Page Hierarchy_OrgChart does not exist' when i open the VF page through the URL 'https://c.cs11.visual.force.com/apex/Hierarchy_OrgChart?id=500Z00000057Wm1'.
This page is present in the managed package, why would be this be shown as page not found when the page is existing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to include the namespace in the URL e.g. `https://cs11.force.com/apex/abc__Hierarchy_OrgChart?id=500Z00000057Wm1`, without the namespace you are trying to access an unmanaged page called `Hierarchy_OrgChart` that doesn't exist